# input value doesnt show, but in inspector it does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input element and string variable called **link**. And when i try to add this string like a value inside input element.

I tried to do it by :

1. `$("#inputURL").value(**link**)`
2. `$("#inputURL").attr('value',**link**)`

and also defined at start:

```
var inputRow = $('<input type="url" id="inputURL" class="input-url-link"value="' + **link** + '">');
```

But it doesn't show. I have empty input element but when I inspect element, it have value which equal **link**. And this all running inside of function.

```
var inputRow = $('<input type="url" id="inputURL" class="input-url-link">');
```

P.S. when i try do write 1) and 2) code inside of INSPECT in console - it works. But when i wrote the same inside of code - doesnt work

Comment: The function on an input is [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) not `value()`.

Comment: Are you able to show the link anywhere else or console log it? Link may not be defined like you expect.

Comment: Why are you adding an extra `</div>` at the end?

Comment: @HereticMonkey sorry. i wrote here bad but in code i tried with .val()

Comment: No problem here with `.val()` or `.attr()` : https://jsfiddle.net/wt3hrjcs/

Answer (score 0):

Use `val()` function so your JQuery will look like this:

```
$("#inputURL").val(**link**);
```

If it doesnt work, try:

```
$("#inputURL").text(**link**);
```

Reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: I made mistake in description but not in code. ( in code i used .val() )

Answer (score 0):

Like @Learner said in his answer, it's $('#id).val() not value().

And I did some simple code to replicate your situation, it works fine.

I'm guessing you should have wrapped your jQuery code in `jQuery(function($){})`

See here https://jsfiddle.net/calmdown/74wurk50/4/